# Mass is rigidity?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, mass

In General Relativity, a totally rigid body cannot be accelerated. It will behave like something of infinite mass.

Similarly a body of two separated particles which connected to each other with a highly rigid bond, will be difficult to accelerate. The more rigid bond is, the more difficult will it be to accelerate the system.

As such, my question is, can any particle's mass be a measure of rigidity of the bonds of its fundamental components?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the derivation of the result that a totally rigid body cannot be accelerated?

Comment: I think the wordy explanation is that if a body is perfectly rigid then a signal would travel instantaneously though the medium violating special relativity.

Comment: @JohnRennie I guess he means that a solid bar will suffer relativistic contraction. So a rigid body won't be able to accelerate. I don't know if rigidity in an external frame of reference has any meaning.